# Catalog Price Rules "Apply Rule" button not showing

Tags: magento2, catalog, catalog-rules

We have tried to create **catalog rules** with **category condition** and it's not working. Also, we are unable to see **Apply Rule button**.

[image: "Apply Rule" button not showing]
Please help

Comment: Hi @Ankur Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Someone reported this in Magento repo.
At this moment don't know if it is bug.

But you can activate the rule by "scheduler" and set an activation time.
[#14956](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14956)